# not getting response from ajax call in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, json, codeigniter

I am trying to check if the user name is available for use using ajax and codeigniter. I have problem to get the response from the codeingniter controller in my js. file but without success.

Here is the controller function, relevant to the question:

```
if ($username == 0) {  
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode(array("r" => true)));
} else {   
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode(array("r" => false, "error" => "Username already exits")));
}
```

Rest assured that I do get 1 if username already exists in thedatabase and 0 if it does not exist.

I have the following js.file

```
// list all variables used here...
var
    regform = $('#reg-form'),
    memberusername = $('#memberusername'),
    memberpassword = $('#memberpassword'),
    memberemail = $('#memberemail'),
    memberconfirmpassword = $('#memberconfirmpassword');



regform.submit(function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

console.log("I am on the beggining here"); // this is displayed in console


var memberusername = $(this).find("#memberusername").val();
var memberemail = $(this).find("#memberemail").val();
var memberpassword = $(this).find("#memberpassword").val();
var url = $(this).attr("action");

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $(this).attr("action"),
    dataType: "json",
    data: {memberusername: memberusername, memberemail: memberemail, memberpassword: memberpassword},
    cache: false,
    success: function(output) {
        console.log('I am inside...'); // this is never displayed in console...
            console.log(r); // is never shonw in console
            console.log(output); is also never displayed in console  
    $.each(output, function(index, value) {
            //process your data by index, in example



        });
    }


});
return false;

})
```

Can anyone help me to get the username value of r in the ajax, so I can take appropriate action?

Cheers

Comment: Can you put a console.log(output) between success: and $.each and edit your post.

Comment: Hi, move it there, and I get nothing. Then I move there all 3 console.log statements, and I get nothing again....I have edited the post as well.

Comment: It's because you never receive a success response. Are you sure you don't print anything after using $this->output->set_output ?

Comment: No, those lines are the last ones in the code

Comment: Can you dump $(this).attr("action"), is it the good URL ?

Comment: Yes, otehrvise it would not find the right controller and right function. That line is just fine. I get the result in the controller that  I want, my problem is to get the respnse in the success. If check using the .fail method, I get parseerror thrown. Do you know what does it mean?

Comment: You need to open up the network tab on either Chromes Developer Tools, or Firebug for Firefox. Filter by XHR, and you should see your ajax request, and be able to inspect what response you are receiving. This is the best way to debug problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you're saying that the `success` handler is never called - meaning that the request had an error in some way. You should add an [`error`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) handler and maybe even a [`complete`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) handler. This will at least show you what's going on with the request. (someone else mentioned about using Chrome Dev Tools -- YES, do that!)

As far as the parse error. Your request is expecting json data, but your data must not be returned as json (it's formatted as json, but without a content type header, the browser just treats it as text). Try changing your php code to this:

```
if ($username == 0) {  
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode(array("r" => true)));
} else {   
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode(array("r" => false, "error" => "Username already exits")));
}
```